# The Popular Letter Chessboard

Tags: optimization, english, checkerboard, word-search

You are given a Chess board with black and white squares.

- You must fill your Chess board with Merriam Webster English words, or other equivalent dictionnaries if you prefer such that each square contains a letter ;
- You can fill vertically or horizontally but not diagonaly ;
- You can have more than one word in a row or column. For instance: **puzzle** and **be** ;
- You can only use a word once.

On your final grid, a letter (actually several is also mathematically possible) will be more frequent than all the other letters. Your aim is that this letter appears as much as possible. If it appears on a white square, you score one and if it appears on a black square, you will score two.

On the next incomplete example, letter E is the most frequent, it appears 6 times. Twice in a black square and four times in a white one. So, up to now, this example scores 8. It is not complete because 25 squares are empty on bottom right and 10 are also missing on bottom left.

[image]

Note that the different words used on this example are:

> Examples, A, Puzzles, Puzzle, Be and Chess.

Which grid with highest score can you find?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The rules of the question state that:

> *On your final grid, a letter **(actually several is also mathematically possible)** will be more frequent than all the other letters. Your aim is that this letter appears as much as possible.*

If we interpret this to mean that *all letters appearing with the greatest frequency contribute to the score* then it is possible to achieve:

> **the maximum score of 96!**

Like so:

> [image]
>
>  Here, the letters A, E, S and T appear with equal (and *greatest*) frequency - 16 times each. Under this interpretation of the rules, *every space scores points!* With 2 for a black and 1 for a white, that makes 64 + 32 = 96 points total.
>
>  The words in the diagram above are:
>
>  SEATS / TEA
>  SEAT / TEAS
>  SATES / EAT
>  SATE / EATS
>  TEATS / SEA
>  TEAT / SEAS
>  SAT / TEASE
>  AT / TEASES
>
>  All are common dictionary words.

Comment: *Best abuse of the rules 2020*

Comment: However, the words "eat" and "ate" and "sea" appear many times, thus breaking the rule: *You can only use a word once.*

Comment: @chasly Note that the OP's own example included both PUZZLE and PUZZLES - it doesn't matter if words appear multiple times *within other words*, you just have to *use* different words. All 16 of the words I have made the decision to *use* (listed in my answer) are unique and thus valid! :)

Comment: Just being skeptical here, but are you sure the "maximum score" is 96?

Comment: @KingLogic Pretty sure - 2 for a black, 1 for a white, 32 of each, all used :)

Comment: @Stiv a couple improvements: first word on the second-to-last row can be changed to "set", increasing 1 more point. Tea (second word of the first row) change to tee (as in golf), another point. Fifth row, second word change to see, sixth row, second word change to sees

Comment: @KingLogic But that would actually *reduce* the scores...! This only works at present because all 4 letters appear 16 times each, tying for 'most frequent'. Increase the number of E's to the detriment of other letters and you lose *all* of the points earned by A, S and T!

Comment: @KingLogic Those changes would make the e appear more frequently than the other letters, so he would lose a ton of points. This only works because each letter appears the same number of times, so every single square is pointed. Since he gets points for every square, he has the absolute maximum number of points

Comment: I am only disappointed that 'tsetse' is not one of the words used.

Comment: I didn't plan to get such a (great) solution and I don't know if I should tick yours or Lukas'. So if I hesitate, that means I should follow the community which upvoted you most, congrats :)

Answer (score 10):

To start things off, here's one with a score of **70**

> [image]

The words are

> eleven
>  ex
>  tehee
>  eve
>  exede
>  see
>  [levee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/levee)
>  [ewe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ewe)
>  [eke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eke)
>  [pewee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pewee)
>  [resee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/resee)
>  [ere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ere)
>  [ebenezer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ebenezer)
>  melee
>  eye

Comment: All black squares with an "e". That is sort of beautiful :)

Comment: The other two high-efficiency words you could try and squeeze in are "ere" and "epee", which could potentially get you up to 72.

Comment: Definitely +1 and deserves to be co-ticked if possible :)